# What's the difference between A-Type game and B-Type game?

Tags: tetris

This question is about the NES Tetris, USA version.

[image: The NES Tetris' main menu]

In the main menu of the Tetris, you can choose between A-Type and B-Type. I know that it changes the ending ([A-Type](https://youtube.com/watch?v=gmmOKF6lDuQ), [B-Type](https://youtube.com/watch?v=0jpGCEJHjy8)), but am wondering if it has any other effects in the game.

Does changing the Type have any other effect in the game?

Comment: USA version as I wanted to play in 60fps rather than 50fps.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A-type is your standard endurance game, you start with the usual empty field, and you're just looking for scoring. Speed increases with every 10 lines cleared.

B-type is something that, to the best of my knowledge, is only present on some of the older Tetris games (both the NES Tetris and the Game Boy Tetris had this) and tasks you with getting 25 lines at a given speed, with a starting field that contains blocks based on the height setting you selected. At higher speeds and heights, it is entirely possible you might have an unwinnable setup.